# AngularJS: How to call function on $resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean, resolve

I am using a MEAN stack. Upon loading a page, I am pulling data. Based on that data, I am making calculations.

I was trying to do calculations based off the model being `$resolved`. I was looking to see if there was an event I could trigger from?

Here is what is being called on `ng-init`

```
// Find existing Vital
$scope.findOne = function () {
    $scope.vital = Vitals.get({
      vitalId: $stateParams.vitalId
    });
};
```

If I try to call my `calculate()` right away, like below, it fails because data isn't there yet

```
// Find existing Vital
$scope.findOne = function () {
    $scope.vital = Vitals.get({
      vitalId: $stateParams.vitalId
    });
    $scope.calculate();
};
```

Comment: Please show the code you have and be sure to make it as simple as possible in order to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: What exactly does the function `.get` do? Is it an async function? Does it return a promise? It's seems like it's from some library, but your question doesn't specify anything. Same with `$scope.calculate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.findOne = function () {
    $scope.vital = Vitals.get({
      vitalId: $stateParams.vitalId;
      $scope.calculate();
      $scope.$apply()
    });
};
```